# Why $\frac {(1+x)^n}{x^k} \ge \sum_{i=0}^k \binom {n}{i} \frac {1}{x^{k-i}} \ge \sum_{i=0}^k \binom {n}{i} $?

Tags: inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

> How does the second inequality hold? For $x \gt 0 $ and $ n \ge k \ge 0 $, $$\frac {(1+x)^n}{x^k} \ge  \sum_{i=0}^k \binom {n}{i} \frac {1}{x^{k-i}} \ge \sum_{i=0}^k \binom {n}{i}
> $$  because $ x \in (0,1) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\frac{(1+x)^n}{x^k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\frac{x^i}{x^k} \ge \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i}\frac{x^i}{x^k}$$ provided that $k$ is a non-negative integer, and $k \le n$.

Comment: I provided less information mistakenly, but updated the question, thanks! I understood now.